# 2007 toyota corolla speedometer,odometer not working, ABS light is on

Tags: toyota, corolla, odometer

2007 Toyota corolla speedometer not working and the ABS light is on.Tried to clean the sensors on both sides of the wheels, can't get it right.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if your Corolla is this way, but if the car uses the wheel sensor(s) to calculate the speed of the vehicle and a sensor is bad, not only would the ABS light be on (because of the bad sensor), but the bad sensor would also prevent the speedometer and the odometer from working.

You need to utilize a code reader (one which can read ABS systems) to find out which speed sensor is bad (if that's what the issue is). Replacing these on your Corolla does not appear to be overly difficult, as there is just one bolt and one connector. Be aware, you need to know where your vehicle was produced, as there are different parts listed for vehicles built in Japan and the USA.